# Mac Terminal can't run most commands after restarting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, github, terminal, zsh

I am using a mac. I have a customised terminal `zsh`, and it was fine for a while. But after I restarted my computer, it started to behave differently:

- The terminal stopped running commands such as `rake` or `rails`.
- I have already created applications using rails, but using a rails command like `rails -v` now gives me this:

  ```
  Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
  ```
- The terminal used to display a tilde `~` instead of my username and that has also stopped. It now displays the full username:

  ```
  Gustaves-MacBook-Air% $ sudo gem install rails
  ```

I have no idea why it doesn't work, and why restarting the computer would break it, even though I've done it before.

I can't even re-download rails:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
zsh: command not found: $
```

because I have customised my terminal long ago following an online setup.

Comment: Hi. Can you try running `echo $0` and `echo $PATH` and share the output?

Comment: echo $0 : /bin/zsh
echo $PATH :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/gustavevilsboe/.rbenv/shims:/Users/gustavevilsboe/.rbenv/bin

Comment: I see you're using rbenv. Have you several versions of Ruby installed too?

Comment: I am not sure if It's even possible to have several versions of Ruby installed, but here is the output from ruby -v :     ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

Comment: Try running `source ~/.zshrc` and also open it using your favourite editor, e.g. `vim ~/.zshrc` and see if it matches what you'd expect from the https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh instructions. Then run `ruby -v` again and see if you get the same result as before.

Comment: after running source ~/.zshrc, I get the answer : source: no such file or directory: /Users/gustavevilsboe/.zshrc but after running vim ~/.zshrc i get a menu telling me " Found a swap file by the name "~/.zshrc.swp" " and " Swap file "~/.zshrc.swp" already exists! "

Comment: You say the command `rails` stopped running, and then you say `rails -v` returns a certain result. That is a contradiction.

Comment: The source of the problem is found. Your ~/.zshrc has been clobbered somehow. You could copy/rename that swap file, or recover it using vim (see instructions [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swap_file_%22...%22already_exists!_-_so_diff_it)) or grab [the default one from the oh my zshell project](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/templates/zshrc.zsh-template).

Comment: Following your advice, i replaced the contents of .zshrc.swp to the default one from oh my zsh project, but I am still getting errors, because a lot of core files seem to be aliases `The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “.rspec” can’t be found. ` Restarting the terminal also prompts : `/Users/gustavevilsboe/.zshrc:107: unmatched "` Wouldnt it be better to manually remove all zsh related files and redownload the whole thing? If so, do you have any tips as to how I should attempt that , because I dont want to break my entire pc deleting the wrong files @iain?

Comment: just pointing out uninstall_oh_my_zsh returns "command not found", thus the question.

Comment: You can simply delete the ~/.oh-my-zsh (`rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh`) and `rm ~/.zshrc` (it's all just text files, basically, your zsh install won't be touched). After that I'd open a new terminal window and [run the install script](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#basic-installation) again. If you can't find an executable, like `git`, then run `which git` to find it.

Comment: Thank you, I have deleted zsh using the two commands you provided, redownloaded zsh and manually added the plugins needed in the ~/.zshrc file. Everything is now in order, Thank you so much for your quick replies.

Comment: No bother, if you look back to a few years ago you'll find I was on this site asking very similar questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this problem, through other people's help:

First I deleted the broken files using

```
rm -rf ~/.oh-my-zsh
rm ~/.zshrc
```

Then I ran the following command to re-download zsh

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Finally, I opened the hidden .zshrc file with text editor to add the plugins i needed

```
plugins=(
  git
  bundler
  dotenv
  osx
  rake
  rbenv
  ruby
)
```

After restarting the terminal, everything was working again

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting zsh:

```
exec /bin/zsh
```

or

```
exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: here is the result from echo $PATH : /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/gustavevilsboe/.rbenv/shims:/Users/gustavevilsboe/.rbenv/bin

Comment: Hi Antranig. Please use comments for questions and the answer facility to provide your solution to the problem.

Comment: @iain didn't get how to write a comment. I use Android "Stack Exchange"

Comment: No problem, it's easily done. Glad you're here to contribute! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your Ruby environment for the directory you're in hasn't loaded properly (hence the missing Rails). It also appears your ZSH environment hasn't loaded properly (the missing `~` is a clue). Why this is, I can't be sure but I'll add some things you can do to help in the meantime.

#### Use [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) with binstubs and a path

I sandbox my projects by installing all the gems into the project directory using the following command:

```
bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor.noindex
```

That will put things like `rails` into `bin` and gems under `vendor.noindex`. The "noindex" part stops Spotlight from indexing that directory, a real irritation for me!

### Make sure ZSH is your default shell

The command for this is:

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

To see what the current default is run `echo $0`.

### Check your ~/.zshrc is in good order

If your prompt doesn't look right then perhaps the file is in bad shape or didn't load properly. Check the instructions for [Oh My Zshell](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

### Check your PATH isn't being mangled

Your `PATH` looks like it's missing the front, as it begins with a colon. Check any zsh plugins you've added are working (maybe remove them all to start with and add them back in one by one).

I also use a ~/.zshenv and a [helper to get paths set up correctly](https://github.com/yb66/path_helper), maybe it will help you. I add this to my ~/.zshenv.

```
if [ -x /usr/local/libexec/path_helper.rb ]; then
  PATH=$(/usr/local/libexec/path_helper.rb -p "")
  DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=$(/usr/local/libexec/path_helper.rb --dyld "")
  C_INCLUDE_PATH=$(/usr/local/libexec/path_helper.rb -c "")
  MANPATH=$(/usr/local/libexec/path_helper.rb -m "")
fi
export PATH
export DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
export MANPATH
```

Hope that helps.